# How generate python 3 compatible code by apache thrift

Tags: python, thrift

This command generates python2 code:

```
thrift -r -gen py temp.thrift
```

Then I tried:

```
thrift -r -gen py3 temp.thrift
```

but that is not working.

Comment: Just as a sidenote: An error description consisting only of "*It does not work*" [without any further details](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise) is **not sufficient** and prone to be gnored, closed, downvoted and other bad things. This wastes our time and yours too.

Answer (score 2):

The command line help reveals all options:

```
thrift  --help
```

These are all available python-related options available in master today:

```
  py (Python):
    twisted:         Generate Twisted-friendly RPC services.
    tornado:         Generate code for use with Tornado.
    no_utf8strings:  Do not Encode/decode strings using utf8 in the generated code. Basically no effect for Python 3.
    coding=CODING:   Add file encoding declare in generated file.
    slots:           Generate code using slots for instance members.
    dynamic:         Generate dynamic code, less code generated but slower.
    dynbase=CLS      Derive generated classes from class CLS instead of TBase.
    dynfrozen=CLS    Derive generated immutable classes from class CLS instead of TFrozenBase.
    dynexc=CLS       Derive generated exceptions from CLS instead of TExceptionBase.
    dynimport='from foo.bar import CLS'
                     Add an import line to generated code to find the dynbase class.
    package_prefix='top.package.'
                     Package prefix for generated files.
    old_style:       Deprecated. Generate old-style classes.
```

According to [THRIFT-1857](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1857), py 3 is available starting at 0.10.0.

Comment: If I am reading THRIFT-1857 correctly, py3 support is in 0.10.0

Comment: I concur with @AOrona. It is in 0.10.0
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRAVATA-2246

Comment: I can confirm this, I had to compile with thrift v 0.10.0 to have py3 compatability. edited the answer to correct this :)